# Overlapping lists with equal hierarchy in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

With Microsoft Word (I am using 2016), is it possible to have overlapping blocks automatically numbered independently of one another ?

I currently do this with lists, basically having to separate lists none of which is a sub list of the other, but the numbering is very dodgy, and my doing it correctly is more about luck and fiddling around than anything else.
I am aware that LateX does this very well and I know how to use it, but I would rather stick with Word here.

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don’t try to modify Word’s built-in ListStyle to do this ... you’ll only become frustrated. Instead, create your own custom list style.

Using the Style Dialog create two new paragraph styles, call them as an example MyStyle1 and MyStyle2. Don’t worry about formatting them yet, just get them built. But do think about how you will be using them and decide now if you want them in your Normal template and if so, check the appropriate box on the dialog as shown here:

[image]

Next using the same Style dialog use the pull-down menu where it says Paragraph and choose List. This will make a ListStyle, which is a special controlling function for numbered or bulleted lists. It’s the thing that makes lists work.

When you change that pull-down menu from Paragraph to List the dialog switches and looks like the following:

[image]

Make sure you give your Custom List Style a unique name and don’t worry about anything else on this dialog other than the Format button in the bottom left and use it to select Numbering.

Clicking OK brings up the final dialog you will work with to build your custom list style and link those two custom paragraph styles to the this custom list style controller.

[image]

If what you see is not like what I’m showing here, click the More... button in the bottom left of the dialog and it will expand to show what I’m showing you here.

Multi-Level list can be up to 9 levels, and you see that level number on the left side of the dialog. Clicking those numbers, in your case just number 1 and number 2, you assign them respectively to MyStyle1 (level 1) and MyStyle2 (level 2).

Make sure your MyStyle2 settings look like I have shown here so instead of level 2 being started with a) b) c) etc. It begins with a number 1.

When ready click Ok and test out your new custom style list. Assign a keystroke or button to MyStyle1 to get your first level. After entering your Exercise 1 label press enter. The next paragraph will be numbered 2. Press tab and it will indent and the subordinate list begins with 1 again. Use Shift + Tab to move back up a level.

[image]